# Could someone help me identify this insect from Malaysia?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Could someone help me identify this insect? My grandfather went on holiday to Malaysia and found this interesting beetle it looks like and has been trying to find out what it is, he placed it in resin to preserve it and I was hoping someone might have the answer to what it could be. The beetle itself is about two inches long and is mostly a vibrant yellow. and sorry the picture is so blurry [image: insect from Malaysia]

Comment: I don't know the species, but it's from the superfamily *Pentatomoidea*, probably family *Pentatomidae*.

Comment: I agree. Not a beetle, but a true bug.

Answer (score 3):

That is *Catacanthus incarnatus* (Pentatomidae). http://cyy4993.blogspot.com/2012/11/stink-bug-pentatomidae-catacanthus_17.html
http://eol.org/pages/3685880/overview

Comment: aka Man-faced Stink Bug